# how to desrialize json to object in python or django

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am new to python and django. i must consume a web service and the response of web service is json like this:

```
[{'name': 'gfile1.txt', 'length': 448, 'createdDate': '1582229671352'}, {'name': 'gfile2.txt', 'length': 86, 'createdDate': '1582229671474'}, {'name': 'soc-LiveJournal1.txt', 'length': 1080598042, 'createdDate': '1582229715227'}]
```

also i have a class according to this json result: the below is class definition:

```
class DataParameter:
    def __init__(self, name, size, _createdDate):
        self.filename = name
        self.filesize = size
        self.createdDate = _createdDate
```

what should i do is:
i must convert the above json to list of DataParameter class.
Can you help me to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using django-rest-framework?

Comment: yes the json is the result of request.get(url):

Comment: why not use DRF parser https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#setting-the-parsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can try something like this:

```
data = [
    {'name': 'gfile1.txt', 'length': 448, 'createdDate': '1582229671352'},
    {'name': 'gfile2.txt', 'length': 86, 'createdDate': '1582229671474'},
    {'name': 'soc-LiveJournal1.txt', 'length': 1080598042, 'createdDate': '1582229715227'}
]


class DataParameter:
    def __init__(self, name, size, _createdDate):
        self.filename = name
        self.filesize = size
        self.createdDate = _createdDate


new_list = []

for i in data:
    new_list.append(DataParameter(i['name'], i['length'], i['createdDate']))

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty alternative

```
class DataParameter:
    def __init__(self, name, size, _createdDate):
        self.filename = name
        self.filesize = size
        self.createdDate = _createdDate

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_str):
        lst = []
        for dct in json:
            lst.append(cls(**json_dict))
        return lst

#Usage 
my_json = [{'name': 'gfile1.txt', 'length': 448, 'createdDate': '1582229671352'}, {'name': 'gfile2.txt', 'length': 86, 'createdDate': '1582229671474'}, {'name': 'soc-LiveJournal1.txt', 'length': 1080598042, 'createdDate': '1582229715227'}]
DataParameter.from_json(my_json)
```